# SalesForce web service - The request element was not recognized

Tags: c#, soap, salesforce, asmx

We are using outbound notification services from SalesForce.

After generating a proxy from the SalesForce WSDL and attempting to send it into my ASMX web service I get the following error

The request element http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound'> was not recognized.

On my C# ASMX web service I have

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://services.company1.com.au/services")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
[SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle = SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]
public class ImportPosition : WebService, NotificationPort
```

The SalesForce WSDL has the following soap definitions

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"
         xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:ent="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
         xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
```

If I change my C# ASMX web service namespace to be 'http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound' the request successfully comes in but as a null object.

Using Wireshark I can see the SOAP message coming in as

```
<notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"
```

Any idea what is causing this namespace problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong tool to generate my proxy.

I should have been using wsdl.exe and not svcutil.exe

Tips for creating a web service to receive outbound notifications from SalesForce

```
use .asmx 
WS-I Basic Profile 1.1 
Web Service Description Language (WSDL) 1.1
Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) 1.1
```